# AWS Elastic Beanstalk chown PythonPath error

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a web app on AWS's elastic beanstalk and am coming across the same error:

`[StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: chown /var/app/staging/venv/bin/python: no such file or directory.`

I see in my environment configuration the property: `PYTHONPATH` : `/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin`

My app runs perfectly fine locally with the command 'python applicaiton.py'.

Any advice on how I can fix this?

Comment: Use .ebignore to remove any files you don't want uploaded to AWS EB

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you aren't pushing your local venv to your EB referenced Git Repo. I was trying to make updates from another machine and accidentally pushed it to master which caused this exact error. I had to use the following to remove it even after adding to gitignore file. Give that a shot and/or double check.

```
git rm -r --cached venv
git commit -m 'Remove the now ignored directory venv'
git push origin master
```

Comment: Look into [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) to help in the future.

Comment: I had the same issue. In my case the did not add the `venv` to in my `.ebignore` so it was getting deployed to servers. I had then added `venv` in my .`ebignore` and got this error message. I resolved it by setting my autoscaling policy to 0. Once the instances were removed from the environment, I reverted the autoscaling policy back to what it was

Answer (score 5):

I discovered that `eb deploy` was deploying my local venv directory, even though it was in .gitignore. I confirmed this by going to "Application versions" in the sidebar and downloading the deployed .zip file under the "source" column. Sure enough, my venv was in there.

I was running `eb deploy` from a subdirectory in my git repo. As I intended, `eb` was only deploying this subdirectory. However, for some reason, it was ignoring the .gitignore file I had in this subdirectory. I added a .ebignore file and put my venv in there, and it fixed the problem. Note that when using .ebignore, `eb` no longer deploys what's commited in git, but rather what's in the working directory. More [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html).