# "eb create" deploys .venv directory, even although it's included in .ebignore file

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a Flask API to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk through the eb CLI, following the [instructions here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) and even although my `.ebignore` file is set to ignore the `.venv` directory, it's still deployed to Elastic Beanstalk.

My `.ebignore` file reads as follows:

```
migrations
tests
.vscode
.venv
.env
.git
.gitignore
__pycache__
```

And yet on every deployment I attempt, I get an `Error: chown /var/app/staging/.venv/lib64: no such file or directory` error, because the `.venv` folder is being deployed.

I've deleted both the application environment as well as the application itself and the error persists. Furthermore, as [this answer indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68375052/14311397), I downloaded the source of my application and the `.venv` directory is there... but it only has a `lib64` file. The other contents are not there. And, as you can see, other directories mentioned in the `.ebignore` were successfully ignored:

[image]

What could cause this problem? Is there some sort of AWS cache I'm not aware of that makes .venv` persist between application & environment creation and deletion?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [this is an eb CLI bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli/issues/69) in which symlinks get added to the `.zip` file created upon running `eb init` regardless of whether their parent directory is added in the `.ebfignore`. I tried adding the parent directory with a trailing slash, with an asterisk wildcard, etc... to no result.

I ended up ditching the `.ebignore` and relying on the `.gitignore` file, which worked fine. So not a solution per se, but rather a workaround until the bug gets fixed.